# how to slide in and out of items of a list with react transition group

Tags: react-transition-group

I followed the tutorial [here](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group) and it works. How do I change the css to get slide in (when enter) and slide out (when leave).

Currently the css is like this:

```
.item-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.item-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}
.item-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.item-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.item-enter {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.item-enter-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.item-exit {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.item-exit-active {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```